# indexOf("1") returns -1 , when there is a 1 in my array

Tags: javascript

indexOf("1") returns -1 , when there is a 1 in my array.

I want to know where every position of "1" is, cause I want to eventually want to create a loop to count every how many time "1" is in the array.

```js
var first_sudoku = [
  ["X", "X", "X", "X"],
  ["1", "X", "2", "X"],
  ["X", "1", "4", "X"],
  ["2", "X", "X", "1"],
];

function counter_for_numbers_in_chart(sudoku) {
  console.log(sudoku.indexOf("1"));
}

counter_for_numbers_in_chart(first_sudoku);
```

Comment: No, there is no element `"1"` in the `first_sudoku` array. What result do you expect and why?

Comment: Hint : `"1" != ["X", "1", "4", "X"]`

Comment: You want to get index of "1" in each array or you want to get first array which contains "1"?

Comment: Do you really want the *index*, or do you just want to know if there's `"1"` anywhere in there at all?

Comment: [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: I want to know where every position of "1", cause I want to eventually count every how many time "1" is in the array

Comment: @sergiomendoza - Note that a *position" in a 2D matrix is two numbers (the row index and the column index within that row). And if you want to find **every** position, you need to remember a list (probably an array). Your best bet is probably a nested loop: The outer loop loops through `first_sudoku`, your inner loop loops through each "row" (nested array) in it. When you find a match, remember that somewhere (such as another array). **But**, if you just want the count, you don't need to remember the positions, just remember the count.

Comment: how about this ```first_sudoku.indexOf(first_sudoku[1])``` and if you use ```first_sudoku.indexOf(first_sudoku[4])``` you get ```-1```

Comment: thanks @ Ibrahim Hammed, this method will work for me!

Comment: works? i posted it in answer and someone marks it down. i dont know youve commented bcos my network went off

Answer (score -1, accepted):

how about this:

```
first_sudoku.indexOf(first_sudoku[1])
```

and you get 1.

if you use:

```
first_sudoku.indexOf(first_sudoku[4])
```

you get -1

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to check the nested arrays for "1".. you could do that like this

```
var first_sudoku = [
      ["X", "X", "X", "X"],
      ["1", "X", "2", "X"],
      ["X", "1", "4", "X"],
      ["2", "X", "X", "1"],
];

var found = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < first_sudoku.length; i++) {
    if(first_sudoku[i].indexOf("1")) {
        found = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

which would set `found` to the first position in the original array that had the item with "1" in it, or found would be -1 if not found.. so a bit like `.indexOf`

Comment: I don't think that's the value the OP is looking for. (If it were, it might be simpler to use `findIndex`. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `for of` loop in your function

```js
var first_sudoku = [
  ["X", "X", "X", "X"],
  ["1", "X", "2", "X"],
  ["X", "1", "4", "X"],
  ["2", "X", "X", "1"],
];

function counter_for_numbers_in_chart(sudoku) {
    for (const row of sudoku) {
        console.log(row.indexOf("1"));   
    }
}

counter_for_numbers_in_chart(first_sudoku);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of arrays. Since `"1"` doesn't exist in the array you called it on (which only has other arrays in it), you get `-1`.

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334891/indexof1-returns-1-when-there-is-a-1-in-my-array#comment126090812_71334891) you've said your actual goal is to **count** all of the `"1"` elements in the arrays. You'd use a nested loop for that:

```
let count = 0;
for (const row of first_sudoku) {
    for (const value of row) {
        if (value === "1") {
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const first_sudoku = [
    ["X", "X", "X", "X"],
    ["1", "X", "2", "X"],
    ["X", "1", "4", "X"],
    ["2", "X", "X", "1"],
];

let count = 0;
for (const row of first_sudoku) {
    for (const value of row) {
        if (value === "1") {
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
console.log(count); // 3
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var first_sudoku = [
  ["X", "X", "X", "X"],
  ["1", "X", "2", "X"],
  ["X", "1", "4", "X"],
  ["2", "X", "X", "1"],
];
```

That is an array of arrays. You won't find a "1"

To actually find the first:

```
var rowIndex = 0;
var colIndex = -1;
for (let row of first_sudoku) {
    colIndex = row.indexOf("1");
    if (colIndex > -1) {
        console.log("row: " + rowIndex + " col: " + colIndex);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: It is. It explains exactly why it's not working!

Comment: Actually, it's an half answer, it explains only *why* and not *how to*